# How to combine 3 updates into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this 3 updates

```
UPDATE [Person]
SET [Email] = @Prefix
WHERE [Id] = @PersonId AND ISNULL([Email], '') <> ''

UPDATE [Person]
SET [Phone] = @Phone
WHERE [Id] = @PersonId AND ISNULL([Phone], '') <> ''

UPDATE [Person]
SET [Skype] = @Skype
WHERE [Id] = @PersonId AND ISNULL([Skype], '') <> ''
```

Can I combine it into one or how can I write more performance operation? Thanks

Comment: One way if they have common column or foreign key, then do a `JOIN` and update. Otherwise use `CASE`.

Comment: Potentially the biggest source of slow performance here is your `WHERE` clauses.  The `ISNULL()` means that even if there is an index on the column being searched, the optimiser can't use it.  I'd suggest playing with `([field] IS NOT NULL OR [field] <> '')` if you have any indexes you want to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mean, you can combine them:

```
UPDATE [Person]
SET [Email] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([Email], '') <> '' THEN @Prefix ELSE [Email] END,
    [Phone] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([Phone], '') <> '' THEN @Phone ELSE [Phone] END,
    [Skype] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([Skype], '') <> '' THEN @Skype ELSE [Skype] END
WHERE [Id] = @PersonId 
AND (ISNULL([Email], '') <> '' OR ISNULL([Phone], '') <> '' OR ISNULL([Skype], '') <> '');
```

Not sure if this will actually improve performance though

Comment: @Mr.Potkin Well, I can't know, you'll need to try it

Comment: `[x] = ISNULL(NULLIF([x], ''), @x)`

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try. However it will overwrite other two value if it just have one new value.

```
UPDATE [Person]
SET [Email] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([Email], '') <> '' THEN @Prefix ELSE [Email] END,
SET [Phone] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([Phone], '') <> '' THEN @Phone ELSE [Phone] END,
SET [Skype] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([Skype], '') <> '' THEN @Skype ELSE [Skype] END
WHERE [Id] = @PersonId 
AND (ISNULL([Email], '') <> ''
OR ISNULL([Phone], '') <> ''
OR ISNULL([Skype], '') <> '')
```

Comment: This has a problem.  If a record has no phone number, but does have an Email, you're going to overwrite the email anyway.

Comment: @MatBailie Edited sql for the same.